# Check if QMediaPlayer playing content

Tags: c++, qt

I have programmed a play music function that runs audio using QMediaPlayer, and I **connected** the function with a QPushButton, when I press the button more than once the music file playing while the first times are still playing, so I need to check the current state of the QMediaPlayer object so I know whether there is an audio file playing now or not.

**widget.h**

```cpp
private slots: 
    void play_music();
```

**widget.cpp**

```cpp
void Widget::play_music() {

    QAudioOutput *outPut = new QAudioOutput;
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
    player->setAudioOutput(outPut);
    player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("E:\\n8mat alphone\\24.mp3"));
    outPut->setVolume(50);
    player->setLoops(-1);
    outPut->setMuted(false);

    player->play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QMediaPlayer::State` enum and `QMediaPlayer::state()` method.

Example:

```
switch(mediaPlayer.state())
{
   case QMediaPlayer::StoppedState:
   //if stopped
   break;

   case QMediaPlayer::PlayingState:
   //if playing
   break;

   case QMediaPlayer::PausedState:
   //if paused
   break;

   default: break;
}
```

You can catch state change via signal `QMediaPlayer::stateChanged`

Doc for State enum here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#State-enum

Doc for state method here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#state-prop

Doc for stateChanged method here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#stateChanged

Comment: i have tried your solution and the Signal return 1 for the PlayingState but i don't know how to connect it with the switch, the switch stopped case always true even if i press the button more than once

Comment: @Shehab, you can connect signal of the button with your custom slot there you can use `switch`  with `QMediaPlayer::State()` method.

Comment: there no method with that name "QMediaPlayer::State()"
i can't add the code in comments so i will make an answer on my post then you can tell me  what to do in comment 
i do prefer if you edit the code that iwill add in the answer, that will help alot

Comment: @Shehab method start with small letter like `state`. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#state-prop

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by Change the QAudioOutPut and QMediaPlayer pointers to the HeaderFile instead of the Widget.cpp